# Trying to create a map with a picture in the upper right corner in R using annotation_custom

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping

Does anyone know how I can insert an image in the upper right corner of a map in r? I have included an example of what I would like to do. If you are able to provide any guidance that would be great. Feel free to use an example of a map (does not need to be with the data provided)

Shapefile data is downloadable at https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/esri::usa-detailed-water-bodies/explore?location=47.162563%2C-94.111383%2C10.27

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(ggsn)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)
library(cowplot)
library(magick)
library(png)
library(ggplot2)

shp = st_read("USA_Detailed_Water_Bodies.shp")
shp

#Plot for BLA
shp$OBJECTID <- as.factor(shp$OBJECTID)

shp_subset <- filter(shp, OBJECTID %in% c('245511'))
shp_subset
Plot <- ggplot(data = shp_subset) + 
  geom_sf()+ 
  coord_sf()+
  theme_bw() + ggsn::scalebar(data=shp_subset2, dist=5, dist_unit="km", height=0.01, transform=TRUE, model="WGS84",location="bottomleft", anchor=c(x=-94.7, y=47.50), st.bottom=FALSE, st.size=2.5, st.dist=0.015)

Plot
#Read in jpg 
img <- readJPEG("Rplot01.jpg", native = TRUE)

img
#Try to plot in upper right corner using x and y values. 
Plot + annotation_custom(rasterGrob(img), xmin = 94.3, xmax = 94.2, ymin = 47.4, ymax = 47.5)
```

[image]

Current Map

[image]

What I want it to look like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your own code is simply that you need negative values to represent degrees West. Here's a fully reproducible example that should achieve what you want.

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsn)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)

shp <- st_read("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/USA_Detailed_Water_Bodies")

shp$OBJECTID <- as.factor(shp$OBJECTID)

shp_subset <- filter(shp, OBJECTID %in% c('245511'))

Plot <- ggplot(data = shp_subset) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  coord_sf() +
  theme_bw() + 
  scalebar(data = shp_subset, dist = 5, dist_unit = "km", height = 0.01, 
           transform = TRUE, model = "WGS84", location = "bottomleft", 
           anchor = c(x = -94.7, y = 47.50), st.bottom = FALSE, st.size = 2.5, 
           st.dist = 0.015)

img <- readJPEG(readBin("https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqqPv.jpg", "raw", 1e6)) %>%
         rasterGrob()

Plot + 
  annotation_custom(img, -94.4, -94.25, 47.4, 47.5) +
  annotation_custom(rectGrob(gp = gpar(fill = NA)), -94.4, -94.25, 47.4, 47.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>